# SharePoint Online deduplicate large list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, csom

I am struggling to find a solution to my case where I have like 300k items in a SharePoint Online list, by accident.
I have generated a file using PowerShell that contains all duplicated items.
I was helped through this article: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/12/sharepoint-online-get-all-items-from-large-lists-powershell-csom.html
The file is built-up as follows:

```
310384,205600
311260,205600
312004,205600
312859,205600
313672,205600
314464,205600
315256,205600
316066,205600
1516,205601
9937,205602
10615,205602
11300,205602
11956,205602
12671,205602
13345,205602`
```

So two columns, left is ID, right is ProjectReferenceNumber.

What I would like to achieve, is that the ProjectReferenceNumber is deduplicated.
And I would probably need to combine these two articles (because the second one does not work for large lists) but I really have no clue how to make this work.

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/12/sharepoint-online-get-all-items-from-large-lists-powershell-csom.html
https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/06/sharepoint-online-find-and-delete-duplicate-list-items-using-powershell.html

Could someone please help me out with this one?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you wanting to remove all the duplicate values or update them to something else?

Comment: Hi Taco thanks for your swift reply. I'm sorry this was not clear. I would like to remove all duplicate ProjectReferenceNumber values, so that this will contain unique values. Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can provide more PowerShell help if needed.

1. Export the list data to Excel, be sure to include the SharePoint ID field.
2. Open Excel and use the de-dupe function to identify duplicates, remove the non-dupe items from the dataset, then save the file. You should now have an Excel file with nothing but duplicate values.
3. Use PowerShell to read from the Excel file and delete items from SharePoint.

Idea:
I'm not sure what the import limitations are for SP and Excel, but you could import the Excel file into a new SP list, then use a Flow to remove the duplicates from your source list. If there are limits on the import size, break the Excel file into smaller chunks, then use Flow to process the data.

Comment: Hi Taco 
I started working on an approach by building a 1-column Excel (xlsx) file, only containing the list item ID's. I started off using a Power Automate flow and by importing the file.
I quickly ran into the Power Automate Excel list rows limit and for each limit.
So I switched over to Logic Apps. I have a 100.000 limit there. Eventually that now seems to work.
Trigger = Recurrence (i.e. once a Month)
Action 2 = List rows present in a table (Excel Online for Business)
For each: ['value']
Action inside for each = Delete item (SharePoint) where id = int(items('For_each')?['Column1'])

Answer (score 1):

1. Trigger = Recurrence (i.e. once a Month)
2. Action 2 = List rows present in a table (Excel Online for Business)
3. For each: ['value']
4. Action inside for each = Delete item (SharePoint) where id = int(items('For_each')?['Column1'])

[image]